# Loop through nested array PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json, loops

I have the following structure (i use json_decode to loop through it on PHP):

```
{"721":{"forms":0},"722":{"forms":"[82]","ope":"48723","ini":"01/03/2015 00:00","fin":"01/03/2015 00:20"},"723":{"forms":0},"724":{"forms":0},"725":{"forms":0},"726":{"forms":0},"727":{"forms":0},"729":{"forms":0},"730":{"forms":0},"731":{"forms":0}}
```

How can I access the property "forms"?

Comment: How did you tried to access it and did you got a error when you tried to access the property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a foreach loop to go through every key/value pair in your array, then just access the forms property of the value array.

```
$a = json_decode($stuff, true); // where $stuff is that JSON string
foreach ($a as $key => $value) {
    print $value['forms']."<br />"
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Just the answer I was needing. Works perfect!